# Gather online players with same IP to a list

Tags: java, ip, bukkit

I run a bunch of alt/bot accounts on my server and I'm trying to make a command that gets all the (online)players IP addresses and if it matches mine, then it adds them to a player list to print to whoever executed the command. Here's what I have so far.

```java
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
  if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("bots")) {
    if (!sender.hasPermission("lbp.bots")) {
      sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You cannot run this command.");
      return true;
    }
    if (args.length == 0) {
      //Player p = (Player) sender;
      List < Player > onlineBots = new ArrayList < Player > ();
      for (Player players: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (players.getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress() == "redacted ip address") {
          onlineBots.add(players);
        }
      }
      sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Luke's Bot List: " + ChatColor.BOLD + "" + onlineBots);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've plugged in my IP address to "redacted ip address", joined my portforwarded local server so i dont join with host IP(double checked my IP registered correctly with essentials /whois) and the command returns an empty list. No errors in console.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykTAX.png
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this code:

```java
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
  if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("bots")) {
    if (!sender.hasPermission("lbp.bots")) {
      sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You cannot run this command.");
      return true;
    }
    if (args.length == 0) {
      List < String > onlineBots = new ArrayList < > ();
      for (Player players: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (players.getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress().equals("insert IP here")) {
          onlineBots.add(players.getName());
        }
      }
      sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Luke's Bot List: " + ChatColor.RESET + "" + ChatColor.AQUA + "" + onlineBots.toString());
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The list was returning players in the CraftPlayer format because of the `List<Player>`, so I changed the list type to `List<String>` and used `onlineBots.add(players.getName());` and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check player IP between you and others. Values between Adress/Host address change a lot, specially between spigot/bungee.

So, I suggest you to use code like this one :

```java
if (args.length == 0) {
   List<Player> onlineBots = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Player players : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
      if (players.getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress().equals(sender.getAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress())) {
          onlineBots.add(players);
      }
   }
   sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Luke's Bot List: " + ChatColor.BOLD + "" + onlineBots);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have over 10 accounts connected to my server at the same time under the same IP as mine since they are my alt accounts. This is why I wanted to do the check for if their IP equals mine then add to list, rather than just getting everybody that isn't the sender. Maybe I just misread your suggestion?

Comment: Oh no, it's me that didn't well understand your request. I just edit my code